# Sprite Kit touchesbegan: delay/lag

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSLog(@"touch");
...
}
```

I have a really simple problem that I can't find any answers to. Most of the time, when I tap the screen, the nslog executes immediately. However, about 1 in 5 times, there is a half second pause before the message displays. I'm making a game and I need the touchesbegan to execute immediately. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? BTW, the framerate is a mostly constant 60 fps.

Comment: are you using a gesture recognizer? They delay touches. Similar when tapping borders where you can swipe up/down for control center and that calendar view thingy

Comment: I don't believe so. Unless the default sprite kit project template is using one.

Comment: you have a `...` What else is in there ? When you say "the message displays", are you talking about that log or are you displaying some kind of ui message in the app ?

Comment: I'm talking about the log. I don't see how what comes after could affect the execution of the log unless I'm totally missing something.

Comment: There were already gesture recognizers in the array from the sprite-kit template. I removed them from the window in the app delegate and the problem is solved. I'm kinda surprised I never heard about this in any beginner tutorials as instant response is crucial in a game. thanks cocos!